# What is the correct current in the datasheet for the LED-Matrix?

Tags: led, led-matrix

If I understood correctly the maximum DC Forward Current for one LED is 30mA (Page 2). So if I wanted to drive an entire column (5 LEDs) I would need 5 times the forward current. If I don't take the maximum but something like 20mA it would result in 100mA per column. Is that correct? Basically I'm wondering if the 30mA is for one LED or for a column.

[Datasheet](http://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/TC20-11SURKWA.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if I wanted to drive an entire column (5 LEDs) I would need 5 times
>   the forward current.

There are 5 columns and 7 rows intersecting with each column: -

[image]

So if you want to drive a full column at 20 mA per LED the column current in total will be 140 mA.

Comment: I'm just using the data sheets references of rows and columns. If you swapped them around it would of course be 100 mA!

Answer (score 1):

The 30 mA is the ABSOLUTE MAX per diode. The normal recommended maximum is 20mA in the section before the absolute max. See the Vf line.

If you want to power 5 leds in parallel, then yes you need 5 times the current.